# Im getting wrong python output format. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python

Total newbie here. Been only learning python for about 2 weeks. So please accept my apology in advance for my code.

Here is the code:

```
import random

name = file = open('IT AMG Employee Names.csv', 'r')

names = file.readlines()

file.close()

print('Hello, Welcome to the IT AMG radom name generator.')

name = (input('What is your name? '))

random_name_qty = (int(input(name + ', How many random names are required? ')))

random_name = (random.sample(names, random_name_qty))

print('Here are your ' + str(random_name_qty) + ' random names: ', random_name)
```

Here is the output:

```
Hello, Welcome to the IT AMG radom name generator.
What is your name? Richy
Richy, How many random names are required? 4
Here are your 4 random names:  ['Julias Vassqusdfez\n', 'Asfvid Busshgbllo Castrsfo\n', 'Jay Ansddreadis\n', 'Andreas Ecvasria\n]
```

-- I assume its very newbie silly minor error
How do i clean up the output for a nicely formatted list?

Thank you for your help.
Richy.

Comment: You should use the `join` method to get a string from your list of random names. Instead of your last print, try `print('Here are your ' + str(random_name_qty) + ' random names: ' + ','.join(random_name))`. This will print more nicely but won't fix those ugly names. Also: try to produce the [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions as it helps understanding and also helps people trying to replicate what you did. This will make you get better answers faster. Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Your `random_name` is a `list` of lines, so when you print `random_name` it will be the [string representation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) of the `list` (i.e. `['Julias Vassqusdfez\n', ...]`)

What you should do instead is iterate through the `list` and print the names one by one:

```
print('Here are your ' + str(random_name_qty) + ' random names: '
for i in random_name:
    print(i)
```

Note: since each of your lines have a `\n` (new line) in it, if you don't want two new lines, you could do this instead:

```
for i in random_name:
    print(i, end='')

# Or

for i in random_name:
    print(i.rstrip())
```

Comment: Thank you both so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
print('Here are your ' + str(random_name_qty) + ' random names: ', ", ".join(random_name))
```

This will join your list together into a comma seperated list!
Although you may want to strip the "\n" off of them depending on how you want it to show up... That can be done to any string using `.strip()`